# Python packaging: get Development Status from version string

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools

One should provide to the setup function in the file setup.py both
the version string and the development status (see
https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
and the project given as example
https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py)

Here a simpler example:

```
from setuptools import setup

import os
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Get the version from the relevant file 
with open(os.path.join(here, 'namepackage/_version.py')) as f: 
    exec(f.read()) 

# In namepackage/_version.py, there is just something like
# __version__= '1.1a2', where 'a' means alpha (see
# http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/).

setup(
    name='namepackage',
    version=__version__,
    # skip arguments for clarity
    classifiers=[
        # How mature is this project? Common values are
        # 3 - Alpha
        # 4 - Beta
        # 5 - Production/Stable
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta'
        ]
)
```

In this case, the version string is written in the file namepackage/_version.py and it also contains the information on the development status, so there should be a way to get the development status as a string ('3 - Alpha' in this example) from the version string. Otherwise, one has to change in a consistent way both _version.py and setup.py, which does not seem very clever (and it's so easy to forget, which would lead to inconsistent informations, as in the example!).

Is there a function to do that in the Python standard library? Otherwise, what would be a clever way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real standard for how alpha or beta is designated in a version string, nor is the classifier required to correlate. I might mark a `0.x` release beta or even alpha status, for example, because I wanted to evolve the APIs still, and not move to production/stable until `1.x`.

So it depends on your own project release policies when to switch classifiers, and if that is correlated to the version string, to implement some string parsing yourself.

This can be as simple as:

```
devstatus = ''Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable'
if 'b' in __version__:
    devstatus = ''Development Status :: 4 - Beta'
elif 'a' in __version__:
    devstatus = ''Development Status :: 3 - Alpha'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are too many ' in the code proposed, but otherwise it would work. If I have to implement that myself, I would do something slightly safer using `from pkg_resources import parse_version`. I still think it is strange that it is possible to use 'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable' with a version string which is clearly alpha or beta, as defined in the PEP 386.

Comment: `parse_version` is great for sorting versions, but not any more useful to test for alpha or beta status, again unless your project has a policy on what terminology to use. `any(p.startswith('*a') for p on parse_version(__version__))` felt too verbose where a simple string containment could suffice.